# change date to all objects in the list and update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, ef-code-first

I am trying to change date to all workouts in the list, the other properties are working fine, its only when I change Date i get problem. I have tried different trouble shooting, but none have worked. I have tried with using updatedWorkout.Date as workoutStart = out of range. If I use old.Date, then, how can I add the new date with 7days a part ?

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Here's my method:

```
    private int UpdateForAllWorkouts(IWorkoutCommand updatedWorkout)
    {
        try
        {   // get schedule
            var schedule = _scheduleRepository.GetIncludeWorkouts(updatedWorkout.ScheduleId);
            // get workouts within the schedule by schedule id
            var workout = schedule.Workouts.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == updatedWorkout.Id);

            for (var workoutStart = workout.Date; workoutStart <= schedule.ToDate; workoutStart = workoutStart.AddDays(7))
            {
                // get specdfic workout by workout id and start time
                var old = schedule.Workouts.Single(w => w.Date == workoutStart && w.StartTime == workout.StartTime);

                var tmp = new Model.Workout
                              {
                                  Id = old.Id,
                                  CourseId = updatedWorkout.CourseId,
                                  InstructorId = updatedWorkout.InstructorId,
                                  Date = //<---problem
                                  StartTime = updatedWorkout.StartTime,
                                  EndTime = updatedWorkout.EndTime,
                                  ScheduleId = updatedWorkout.ScheduleId,
                                  WeekOffSet = updatedWorkout.WeekOffSet.Days
                              };
            }

            return updatedWorkout.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("");
        }
    }
```

thx for helping!

Comment: What problem do you get when setting `Date` field?

Comment: What is the repository in question? Does it understand itself that Workout with Id=old.Id should be updated with the provided values? Because I see you creating new Workouts, not updating the old ones...Is this EntityFramework or L2S (nothing specified in tags)?

Comment: when I set the date through workoutstart = updatedWorkout.Date then I get a out or range.

Comment: Well, it does not understand it self to be updated, the reason I make a new Workout is that the repository takes a data model, but what i get is a domain model. I am using EF CodeFirst approach.

Comment: On which iteration do you get the exception? Is It the first one or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a loop for 7.

like this :

```
var workoutStart = workout.Date;
while(true){

    if(workoutStart <= schedule.ToDate){
    // Do something
    }else{
        break;
    }

    workoutStart = workoutStart.AddDays(7);
}
```

Comment: so you mean I have to make another loop ? is there no other way do it in the first loop ?

Comment: I have tried this solution, but where do I get the new date ?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to check the value of our DateTime properties.Their values could be less than your SQL server allow for datetime field.

- What is the Date value of updatedWorkOut object before you assign "tmp" object ?
- Is your "old" object null or what is the value of date ?

your code seems to be ok. the problem underlies the value of DateTime properties and fields.